# PHP array comparision error

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

I have 2 SELECT statement in my PHP. Both the select statements fetch data from two different DB. The fetched data is saved in PDO Assoc Array. The problem is when I want to compare those two arrays to find that if the column 'id' exist in both arrays or not. If it exists then ignore it. If it's a unique id then save it into a third array. But I found some problems in my Logic Below

And after running the below code I am getting a couple of error:
 1: Array to string conversion
 2: duplicate key value violates unique constraint

```
$arr1 = $msql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$array1 = array();
foreach($arr1 as $x){
$array1[] = $x['id'];
}


$arr2 = $psql->fetechAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$array2 = array();
foreach($arr2 as $y){
  $array2[] = $y['id'];
 }

$finalarray = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < count($arr1); $i++){
if(count(array_intersect($array1,$array2)) <= 1){// is the count of id is 1 or less save that whole row in the $finalarray
      $finalarray = $arr1[$i]; // saving the unique row.
}
else{
    continue;
}
}
```

All I am trying to get the unique row of data array() after comparing their id column.

Comment: You had asked similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49164646/compare-two-arrays-keys-in-php) , should have edited the same question . Please delete older post now

Comment: I did Thank you.

Comment: What line is the error being reported on?

Comment: The code runs fine after @Gufran Hasan fixed it. But the error comes when there is a duplicate already exist in the db while inserting the data which fails to execute the query completely.

Comment: Then  you should either prevent duplicate entries in `$array1` , `$array2` while assigning  or  use array_unique to `$finalarray`

Comment: @samscoot1900 check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `in_array() function` as both arrays are index array.

```
$finalarray = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < count($arr1); $i++){
if(count(array_intersect($array1,$array2)) <= 1){// is the count of id is 1 or less save that whole row in the $finalarray
      $finalarray = $arr1[$i]; // saving the unique row.
}
else{
    continue;
}
}
```

make change in code:

```
$finalarray = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < count($arr1); $i++){
if(!in_array($array1[$i], $array2)){
      $finalarray[] = $array1[$i]; // saving the unique row.
}

}
```

Comment: should be : `$finalarray[] = $array1[$i];` and also no need of continue

Comment: @Gufran Hasan I am getting a syntax error in if statement?

Comment: I have updated my amswer please check it again hope it will for wrok as you are looking

Comment: @GufranHasan I don't know why but still is throwing me an error of unique value exist and then stops inserting?

Comment: @GufranHasan ERROR:  Unique violation: 7 ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint

Comment: Which database you are using MySql or any other?

Comment: It's PostgreSQL

Comment: Okay, Please see this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24447930/postgresql-duplicate-key-value-violates-unique-constraint-on-update-command

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `array_intersect()` to get common values between two array. for difference, can use `array_diff()`

```
$array1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7];
$array2 = [2,4,6];
//array_intersect — Computes the intersection of arrays
$result = array_intersect($array1, $array2);
print_r($result);
//array_diff — Computes the difference of arrays
$result = array_diff($array1, $array2);
print_r($result);
```

[DEMO](https://3v4l.org/JiAPL)

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using 3 different arrays to get unique ids, you can do it by using one array. Make changes to your code as below:

```
$finalarray = array();

$arr1 = $msql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
foreach($arr1 as $x){
    if (!in_array($x['id'],$finalarray)) { // check id is already stored or not       
        $finalarray[] = $x['id'];
    }
}


$arr2 = $psql->fetechAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
foreach($arr2 as $y){  
    if (!in_array($y['id'],$finalarray)) { // check id is already stored or not       
        $finalarray[] = $y['id'];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should make sure which array is larger before your loop ;

Or using array_diff:

```
$finalarray = array_diff($array1 , $array2) ?? [];
$finalarray = array_merge( array_diff($array2 , $array1) ?? [], $finalarray );
```

Comment: My array1() will always be larger then array2()